# i want to make a dropdown menu . I searched for the different techniques but my design is changing

Tags: html, django, drop-down-menu, html-lists, dashboard

[image]

I want to make that **lead**(below Dashboard) to be dropdown menu. without changing my design.

The lead is under **ul** **tag**.

```
<div class="wrapper ">
        <div class="sidebar" data-color="purple" data-background-color="white" data-image="../assets/img/sidebar-1.jpg">
          

          <div class="logo"><a href="http://www.creative-tim.com" class="simple-text logo-normal">
              Creative Tim
            </a></div>
          <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="nav">
                     
              <li class="nav-item ">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'UserProfile' %}">
                  <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                  <p>Lead</p>
                </a>
              </li>
```

Comment: Check this and let me know what is missing, you need to use CSS to modify this. 
https://jsfiddle.net/silvachathura/uadehy2q/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
enter code here
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: This can be made working using JS or jQuery by manipulating CSS ... try above example.